# How do I Include a Powershell script when publishing my VB app?

Tags: vb.net, powershell

I am writing an application in VB.NET. In the app, I have a function which calls a Powershell script and places the resulting information in a text box.

I have two issues:

How to I ensure that when my app is published, the powershell script is included?
How do I reference the script in my code?

Currently, I simply give my function the full path to the script, which is in a folder on my Desktop. Obviously, this will not work once I deploy the app to other computers.

Comment: How do you publish your application?

Comment: Just using the Publish function included with VB. It is simply going to be packaged with a setup file. Users will be installing it on their machines.

Comment: I was able to figure out how to add the script file to the project when compiling it by setting the "Build Action" to Embeded Ressource. However, this has no effect when I publish the project.

Comment: @Coffee Embedding your script won't make it accessible in your client installation program folder - it will get compiled into application assembly.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a Setup project to get your script in place on your target system.

A first step is to change the `Build Action` to `Content` and `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy always`.

Your Setup project can pick up the script from the VB app build result and put it in place when installing your app.

As for your question concerning the user configurable install path: The easiest way to handle this would be to add registry entry containing the selected program file path and have your app read the path from there.

Comment: Can I get some clarification on what you mean by "Setup project"? I apologize if this is obvious, I am pretty new to VB. Thanks!

Comment: @CoffeeStir: What version of Visual Studio?

Comment: Nevermind! I was able to figure it out using the following guide http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Win_App_Setup_Project.aspx. Thank you all for the help!